# C macro/function return multiple types

Tags: c, macros

I have a general object named tfm that can be 3 bigger types (tfm is a the beginning of other 3 types of structs). Based on a field inside the tfm I can determine to which bigger struct the tfm belongs to.
All 3 struct types have a field named in the same way (reqsize), but that is not inside tfm.
Is there some macro magic that can let me do something like this:

```
CAST_UPPER(tfm)->reqsize
```

?
It can be gcc compiler extension specific.

Comment: With enumerated types, inline functions and insanely optimising compilers, the preprocessor is best relegated to including headers and conditional compilation. Its "foibles" are well documented and it should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 3):

Not easily as any expression that had a result (e.g.

```
(tfm)->type == TYPE1 ? (type1*)(tfm) : (tfm)->type == TYPE2 ? (type2*)(tfm) : (type3*)(tfm)
```

) would fail to compile as the various result expressions have different types. You'd have to have something like

```
#define CAST_UPPER(tfm, field) \
    (tfm)->type == TYPE1 ? (type1*)(tfm)->field : \
    (tfm)->type == TYPE2 ? (type2*)(tfm)->field : 
                           (type3*)(tfm)->field
```

IMHO that's rather a fragile design, and you'd do better to have `reqsize` in `tfm`, or at least for the other 3 `structs` to have contain a common `struct` which contained `tfm` and `reqsize`, thus

```
typedef struct TFM { ... } TFM;
typedef struct TFMREQ {
     TFM tfm;
     size_t reqsize;
} TFMREQ;
struct TYPE1 { TFMREQ tfmreq; ... };
struct TYPE2 { TFMREQ tfmreq; ... };
struct TYPE3 { TFMREQ tfmreq; ... };
```

Then you could just do `(TFMREQ *)tfm->reqsize`